# I want to secure my Website Admin Area which in folder named admin

Tags: asp.net

I want to secure my Website Admin Area which in folder named admin i want to allow users to navigate all website pages except admin area must log by user name  & password please help me Doing that .

Comment: I am just trying to identify your actual requirements here,  do you want 1) all users to log in to view the site and restrict access to the admin area totally or 2) allow everybody access to the site without logging in and requiring them to log in if they want access to the admin area?

Comment: following on what Muhammad and Akram said, you can view videos here(http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials) to get more info on asp.net security as well as here(http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/06/19/ASP.NET-2.0-Security_2C00_-Membership-and-Roles-Tutorials.aspx) to get a step by step tutorial guid

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in the `configuration` section of the `web.config`.

```
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>               
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

`<deny users="?"/>` means an `unauthenticated` user will not be able to access the `Admin` Folder.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [Configuring Specific Files and Subdirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbkh9s7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

> Configuration settings can be applied
>   to specific resources by using a
>    tag with an appropriate
>   path attribute. The path attribute can
>   be used to identify a specific file or
>   child directory to which unique
>   configuration settings apply. Only one
>   file path can be used in the path
>   attribute.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true" timeout="10"/>
  </system.web>

  <!-- Configuration for the "sub1" subdirectory. -->
  <location path="sub1">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="sub1" type="Type1"/>
        <add verb="*" path="sub1" type="Type2"/>
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <!-- Configuration for the "sub1/sub2" subdirectory. -->
  <location path="sub1/sub2">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="sub1/sub2" type="Type3"/>
        <add verb="*" path="sub1/sub2" type="Type4"/>
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put a web.config file in admin folder and in that, deny access for all users except the users or roles that must have access:

```
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="admins"/>
        <allow users="user1,user2"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use .htaccess and .htpasswd
you can generate these files here http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/